# WebRTC Safari integration test: How to mock getUserMedia video?

Tags: safari, webrtc, integration-testing

I would like to implement an integration test mocking a WebCam video stream using the Safari browser. Following the [WebRTC testing documentation](https://webrtc.org/getting-started/testing) Chrome provides the `--use-file-for-fake-video-capture=<filename>` flag to mock the video stream. I have not found any documentation for the Safari browser.

Is there a way to fake a webcam video for testing using the Safari browser?